# Using Correlation to calculate features strength in multi class classification

Tags: correlation, feature-selection, skewness

I have 4 categorical features to describe text documents [x1, x2, x3, x4]. And I need to classify each document into one of given classes y.

Given a certain skewed dataset, I have a feeling that feature x1 is highly correlating with y (i.e. depending solely on x1 for classification will yield very high false accuracy). and the rest of the feature are useless.

What would be a useful normalized metric to prove that two categorical variables are highly correlating, so i can end up with a table like that.
and plot the same for other datasets to prove that this is not a common distribution of correlation.

```
+----+-------+------+------+------+
|    |   X1  |  X2  |  X3  |  X4  |
+----+-------+------+------+------+
| Y  |  0.99 |  0.1 | 0.05 |  0.1 |
+----+-------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The answer I am providing below is applicable in python only.

- Pandas, a powerful data analysis library in python, provides two ways to check the correlation between various features present in your data. The first method is to use the the `pandas.DataFrame.corr` method in order to get a correlation matrix. The values in the matrix gives you the estimate how strongly(positively/negatively) are the features related to each other. Suppose your dataframe is represented by `data` containing `n` number of columns represting the features in the dataset. Then you can find the correlation between different features just by calling the pandas method as:
  `data.corr()`. This will output a `n X n` matrix of correlation values. You can read it about more [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html).
- The second method is to plot a scatter matrix using the pandas `scatter_matrix()` method. This method gives you a nice view of the correlation between different features such as shown below:
  [image: scatter matrix in pandas]

You can read about this more [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#visualization-scatter-matrix)

- You can also make use of seaborn heatmap (seaborn is another high level visualization library in python). A heatmap can be used to represent the correlation between different features. This will give you a nice plot as shown below:
  [image: seaborn heatmap]

You can read about it more in detail [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).